# Velocity with double curly braces

Tags: velocity, apache-velocity

Why velocity gives the following output for the string

```
VelocityContext vc = new VelocityContext();
vc.put("foo", "bar");
String inString = "THis is ${{foo}} and this is ${foo}.Hello and ${foo}-Hello";

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
ve.evaluate(vc, sw, "Tag", inString);
```

Output:

```
THis is ${{} and this is bar.Hello and bar-Hello
```

I was expecting it would either print `${{foo}}` or `{bar}`, why `${{}`? Would double curly act as escape character?

I'm using this under strict reference mode set as true. And I neither see an exception nor I see it print it as is and that's what is confusing me.

Comment: what's your velocity version? is it latest 2.0?

Comment: Ah, no. I'm on velocity 1.7

Answer (score 0):

[Velocity Variables](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#variables) or `VTL Identifier`

> Must start with an alphabetic character (a .. z or A .. Z). The rest of the characters are limited to the following types of characters:
>
> - alphabetic (a .. z, A .. Z)
> - numeric (0 .. 9)
> - hyphen ("-")
> - underscore ("_")

You are using [Formal Reference Notation](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#formal-reference-notation) as ${varName}

`${{foo}}` - so velocity try to get variable {foo} which is invalid VTL Identifier so it doesn't try to load the variable.

It probably then try to reference it as a JSON map {"a":"b"} and failed again, probably only `{` is accepted, so you remain with:

${`{`}

I tested your template in new velocity 2.0 and this issue isn't reproduce (in strict or non strict mode)
Output:

```
THis is ${{foo}} and this is bar.Hello and bar-Hello
```

So you have now a reason to upgrade to [velocity 2.0](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention strict reference mode, I'm under strict reference mode and it doesn't throw exception for this case. Neither does it print {foo}, so is the source of my confusion

Answer (score 0):

Well, you made me look into the code and I'm not sure if I understood it correctly. The problem seems to be that in ${...}, the xxx is treated as an ASTReference, which then gets tokenized differently than a standalone string "{bar}". Specifically, it get tokenized into 3 tokens {, bar and }. Then the engine tries to find the so-called root of the reference (in ${x}, the root is x), does not recognize the pattern and goes into a fallback reference type RUNT, which says that the first token, i.e. "{" matters. This way "{bar}" becomes "{".

In other words, the expression ${{bar}} does not make sense and Velocity fails to throw an error here. In other nonsensical combinations like ${[bar]} it actually throws an error.

Comment: Agreed, I rely on Velocity's strict reference mode to sort of validate that no weird identifiers are left un-replaced . With this behavior, I will have to validate separately for this case if it happens to be. That sucks